# Pagination in pages (not posts) with the twentythirteen theme?

Tags: pagination, theme-twenty-thirteen

I wrote a very long page with a lot of content and would like to add a pagination to make it more readable. I added in the texteditor several `<!–-nextpage–->` but it doesn't create any pagination, although in the default twentythirteen page template the `wp_link_pages` function is called

```
<?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-links"><span class="page-links-title">' . __( 'Pages:', 'twentythirteen' ) . '</span>', 'after' => '</div>', 'link_before' => '<span>', 'link_after' => '</span>' ) ); ?>
```

I'm using a child theme with little customizations but I also can't get it to work with the default twentythirteen theme with no child theme and customizations.
How can I get a pagination on my page?

Answer (score 0):

This might work.

1.Open your page.php (or some other custom-page-template.php in which you want to make it work)

2.look for the line where you see

```
<?php the_content(); ?>
```

3.Insert

```
<?php wp_link_pages(); ?>
```

on the very next line like this

```
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php wp_link_pages(); ?>
```

4.Go back to your editor and refresh the preview.

5.Now if its working just publish the page!

If you want to configure it visit the [codex page here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_link_pages)

Comment: I have checked in TwentyThirteen. It already contains that wp_link_page(); thing in the manner you mentioned. and is working absolutely fine(I tried using the tag myself). There might be some other issue. Would need some more explanation.

Comment: I don't understand because I just tried with a fresh install of wordpress and twenty thirteen and it still doesn't work. See [link](http://wp2013.is-great.org) When looking at the "View source code", you can see the `<!–-nextpage–->` . There may be something I misunderstood about this feature even though I read the related codex.

Comment: @kimberleyFurson Sorry for late reply. It is suppose to be "<!--nextpage-->" not like this "<!----nextpage---->" which I saw in your page.